# Rendering react habitat components through HTML thats passed through a prop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, react-habitat

I am currently using react habitat on a project and i have components rendering through like the following

```
<div data-component="MyComponent" data-prop-titl="My title"></div>
```

I have encountered an issue where I am trying to pass through some markup from a rich text editor that contains markup like the example above.

I want to be able to render the rich text with the react-habitat components references inside.

So the reference above can basically be passed through with the rich text and still be rendered out as a react component.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this might help

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: '<div data-component="MyComponent" data-prop-titl="My title"></div>'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

But this is a very risky practice and can expose your users to  a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack

Comment: Sorry mate that's not what I mean - I know how to pass-through HTML but I want to pass in react-habitat references with the HTML and it will load in the right react component with props

Answer (score 0):

I'm the original author of React Habitat.

You are going to run into issues putting HTML into an attribute string. Its the [same problem with JSON](https://github.com/DeloitteDigitalAPAC/react-habitat#use-encoded-json-in-html-attributes)

I would just make the HTML go inside the habitat component then use [the proxy variable the React Habitat sets for you](https://github.com/DeloitteDigitalAPAC/react-habitat#passing-properties-props-to-your-components).

eg

```
 <div data-component="MyWysiwygViewer">
     <h2>Some HTML text</h2>
     <p>With some body</p> 
 </div>
```

In the component i would get this data with:

```
 constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      const html = props.proxy.innerHTML;
 }
```

**Alternatively**

you could put it inside a hidden div

```
 <div id="myHtml" style="display: none" >
     <h2>Some HTML text</h2>
     <p>With some body</p> 
 </div>

 <div data-component="MyWysiwygViewer" data-prop-html-id="myHtml" />
```

Then in the component i would get this data with:

```
 constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      const html = document.getElementById(props.htmlId).innerHTML;
 }
```